# Create yum repo with multiple keys

Tags: package-management, yum, gpg

I need to create a yum repository but I have 5 gpgkeys, the idea is to configure the repo and each package install its own gpgkey automatically. In other words, I need to configure multiple gpgkeys for a repo. How can I do that?

```
[repo]
name=Repo
baseurl=http://url
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey= *** Can I write a url here for each package install its key? ***
```

Comment: It might help if you could add some explanation or context information on the reasoning  **why** you need to use multiple gpg keys for one repo.

Answer (score 2):

Only practical example seems to be mentioned in
[a puppet bugreport - "yumrepo type does not support multiple gpgkey entries"](https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/8867)
which says that you need to use multi-line URLs instead of multiple gpgkey= entries.

Hence it should look like this

```
gpgkey=<url1>
       <url2>
```

and not like this

```
gpgkey=<url1>
gpgkey=<url2>
```

This is also how it's described in the [`yum.conf` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/yum.conf)

> **gpgkey** A URL pointing to the ASCII-armored GPG key file for the
>   repository. This option is used if yum needs a public key to verify a
>   package and the required key hasn't been imported into the RPM
>   database. If this option is set, yum will automatically import the key
>   from the specified URL. You will be prompted before the key is
>   installed unless the assumeyes option is set.
>
> Multiple URLs may be specified here in the same manner as the **baseurl**
>   option (above). If a GPG key is required to install a package from a
>   repository, all keys specified for that repository will be installed.